# Boostrap3: How works sticky footer?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a sticky footer. Fortunately, I found that boostrap has a simple solution : **sticky footer**. But this one is only displayed at the page's left side. How can I displayed at the page's right side? Thank you.

```
<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom"> </div>
```

Comment: right side? this is not a sticky footer, sticky footer stay at page's bottom. `<footer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe boot strap has a helper class `.pull-left` and `pull-right` that perform the action you are desiring.

Answer (score 0):

The sticky footer you say that is [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)?

It is at the bottom.

Do you mean the footer word is at the left site?

It is the `text-align`. You can change the `text-align` and change to the position you want.